# C++ development on OpenVMS and mainframe

Tags: c++, mainframe, openvms

What are particularities of developing C++ on OpenVMS and Mainframe?

I thought OpenVMS were more POSIX than most UNIXes, and most stuff are available, but it seems not.

Comment: Could you give some specifics as to what you find is missing?

Comment: I done some searches, and it seems people have problems with BOOST etc.  My conserns are 1) That less is available of gcc, emacs, gdb Qt etc.  and 2) spesific issues with programming these platforms (threading, memory etc.)

Comment: This was not a good question - I posted a different one:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786458/developing-with-c-on-openvms

Answer (score 1):

It is an overlooked platform, but z/OS UNIX ® System Services is a full and robust implementation of the POSIX standard, as well as several others. In general, it is not a good X platform, but with other packages it is competitive and scalable.

Linux also runs on System z, but as a native or guest OS, not under z/OS.

OpenVMS is not UNIX-compatible and would require much code change. You might find this official HP link helpful:  http://h71000.www7.hp.com/portability/

Answer (score 0):

The IBM mainframes are POSIX compliant since 1996.  OpenVMS, meh, I have no idea.